# Informix SQL: How to get the date part of a datetime field in a query?

Tags: sql, date, datetime, informix

What is the best way to use a only the date part of a datetime field in a query?
I have a datetime field and want to group/count it by date.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are a number of ways of doing it:

```
EXTEND(dt_field, YEAR TO DAY)
CAST(dt_field AS DATETIME YEAR TO DAY)
dt_field::DATETIME YEAR TO DAY
CAST(dt_field AS DATE)
dt_field::DATE
DATE(dt_field)
```

The simplest - as in shortest - are the last two, and the function notation is probably clearest.  The first three leave you with a DATETIME value; the last three leave you with a DATE value.  These are similar, but not identical.  They are fairly freely interchangeable though.

Answer (score 6):

```
date(name_of_field)
```

Answer (score 2):

This

```
to_char(dt_field, "%d %B %Y")
```

gives as `31 May 2016`.

To group:

```
SELECT YEAR(dt_field) year, MONTH(dt_field) month, COUNT(*) count
FROM tblName
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to these...

I was looking for some way to extract parts of dates and times in Informix, and found these, just in case they're useful to anyone, they're all here in one place.

## As text...

- `TO_CHAR(<value>, "%H")` Hours (00 - 23)
- `TO_CHAR(<value>, "%M")` Minutes (00 - 59)
- `TO_CHAR(<value>, "%S")` Seconds (00 - 61)

**[Further TO_CHAR codes...](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1542.htm)**

- `%a` Abbreviated weekday name, as defined in the locale
- `%b` Abbreviated month name, as defined in the locale
- `%C` The century number (the year divided by 100 and truncated to an integer) as an integer (00 through 99)
- `%D` The same as the %m/%d/%y format
- `%e` Day of the month as a number (1 through 31). A single-digit value is preceded by a blank space.
- `%Fn` The value of the fraction of a second, with precision specified by the unsigned integer n. The default value of n is 2; the range of n is 0 ≤ n ≤ 5. This value overrides any width or precision that is specified between the % and F characters.
- `%h` Same as the %b format: abbreviated month name, as defined in the locale
- `%H` Hour as a 2-digit integer (00 through 23) (24-hour clock)
- `%I` Hour as a 2-digit integer (00 through 11) (12-hour clock)
- `%m` Month as an integer (01 through 12). Any single-digit value is preceded by a zero (0).
- `%M` Minute as a 2-digit integer (00 through 59)
- `%S` Second as a 2-digit integer (00 through 61). The second value can be up to 61 (instead of 59) to allow for the occasional leap second and double leap second.
- `%T` Time in the %H:%M:%S format
- `%w` Weekday as a number (0 through 6); 0 represents the locale equivalent of Sunday.
- `%y` Year as a 2-digit decimal number.

## As integers...

- `DAY(<value>)` Day of month (0 - month max)
- `MONTH(<value>)` Month of year (1 - 12)
- `YEAR(<value>)` Year number